# CocoaPods: [!] Unable to find a specification for 'Surge4Swift3'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm new to CocoaPods. I just created a Github project and was hoping to include it in my Pods. It's giving me an error:

`[!] Unable to find a specification for 'Surge4Swift3Plus'.`

I've tried:

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
pod install --verbose
```

Here's my Podfile:

```
target 'MyApp' do
  use_frameworks!

        pod 'Firebase/Core'
        pod 'Firebase/Auth'
        pod 'Firebase/Database'

        pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git'
        pod 'Surge4Swift3Plus', :git => 'https://github.com/dmr07/Surge4Swift3Plus.git'
end
```

Do I need to do something special for the Github project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can include just any git repository in your Podfile. CocoaPods needs to know what it is first. See the below link about making a cocoapod. 
https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html